# What's the use of ActionTypes in Flux?

Tags: javascript, flux

I'm following through the first Flux tutorial at https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-todomvc

I'm a little bit confused as to what the 'TodoActionTypes.js' file actually does.

If anything is unclear on what I'm asking, please let me know and I'll try to clear things up.

I'll try to explain with the onToggleTodo prop of AppView:

```
<AppView /> renders <Main /> which has props.onToggleTodo which is triggered on onChange.
```

So, onChange triggers TodoActions.toggleTodo.

From TodoActions, toggleTodo is triggered and this dispatches an action with type and id to the stores

```
toggleTodo(id) {
    TodoDispatcher.dispatch({
        type: TodoActionTypes.TOGGLE_TODO,
        id,
    });
},
```

In TodoActionTypes.js, there is:

```
const ActionTypes = {
    ...
    TOGGLE_TODO: 'TOGGLE_TODO',
};
```

in TodoStore.js, there is a

```
switch (action.type){
    case TodoActionTypes.TOGGLE_TODO:
```

My question is why is it necessary to have this, and not just simply have 'TOGGLE_TODO' everywhere to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

This pattern provides many benefits over using literal strings:

- Bugs as a result of *incorrectly typing the value manually* are much easier to track. If you were to use a type checking tool like TypeScript, the compiler would clearly mark this. At the very least you would see `undefined` in place of a very similar value that your eyes might automatically consider correct.
- Editors that support refactoring are able to do so in this case.
- The value can easily be changed (both its value and/or type). For example, you might decide down that track that you want to use the values as a bitmask and so you would have to change the type to integers.
- It provides a clear list of possible `TodoActionTypes` for other project contributors.
- It provides the ability to programatically access and reason about the possible `TodoActionTypes` (e.g. with a `for..in` loop).